# Overlay not working when triggered with class from javascript printed tags

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, overlay

With this javascript I'm printing list of records:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        function hide(){
        $('#friend_list').fadeIn(100);
        $('#friend_list').load("friend_list.php");
        };

        setInterval( hide,100 );

    });

</script>
```

in friend_list.php I'm getting all the records relevant for user and returning it like this:

```
echo "<div class='friend' id='friend'>" . $a["username"] . "<input type='hidden' value='$id'/>" . "</div>";
```

And I'm using this simple script to make overlay:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
function overlayerOn(){
    $('#overlayer').fadeIn(800);
}

function overlayerOff(){
    $('#overlayer').fadeOut(800);
};

$('#board').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();});

$('.friend').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    overlayerOn();
    var $br = $('#board');
    $br.css('display', 'block');
    });

$('#overlayer').click(function(e){
    overlayerOff();});
});
</script>
```

Overlay is working as long as I trigger it with some other id or class than the one used from friend_list.php. But that is the one I need. Any idea why overlay is not working when triggered by class .friend?
Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use (live is deprecated)

```
$('.friend').live('click', function(e){
    // your code
});
```

If you are using latest version of jquery then use

```
$('body').on('click', 'div.friend' , function(e){
    // your code
});
```

It's happening because you are loading content dynamically using

```
$('#friend_list').load("friend_list.php");
```

so click is not working because those contents were not in the DOM when it was loaded.

Comment: Right, well I thank you very much, causes you helped me a lot. And I changed interval to 2000 from 100 cause it was to many times not working. I guess it's because that interval that sometimes it opened and sometimes it didn't. Thank you very much anyway. :)

Comment: I have question, how would you take that hidden input value and pushed it to script to send it to another php script? BTW sorry for English.. :)

Comment: Did you mean getting value from a hidden input and send it to php via javascript using ajax ?

Comment: I'm making a fiddle or you, wait, ok ?

Comment: Well I did it already with search, but I was trying this for about 6h and I have to to some mistake I can not see. I use this in overlay but no use:
    $('#board').load("messages.php?val=" + $(this).find('input').val(), hideB());

Comment: I'm getting this: "undefined"